# List implementation in C++

Tags: c++, list

I don't have a problem this time but I am just looking for List implementetion, just a simple List with nodes like Node(int,nextNode). I did it many times in the past but my c++ got little bit rusty. Could you share with me? I was looking in my archive, on github but I didn't find antyhing.

EDIT:

*I decided to do mine and I don't understand why after using delete I still can get 
cout<getWrt()<*

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{

public:
    Node(Node* next, int wrt){
        this->next = next;
        this->wrt = wrt;

    }

    Node(const Node& obiekt){
        this->wrt = obiekt.wrt;
        this->next = obiekt.next;
    }
    ~Node(){}

    void show(){
        cout<<this->wrt<<endl;
    }

    int getWrt(){
        return this->wrt;
    }

    Node* getNext(){
        return this->next;
    }

 private:
    Node* next;
    int wrt;

};


int main()
{
Node* n  = new Node(NULL, 2);
n->show();
Node* n2 = new Node(*n);
n2->show();
delete n;
n->show();
n2->show();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::list`?

Comment: @Pubby: There's nothing wrong with using `std::list` (in terms of using a linked list, anyway).

Answer (score 4):

The basic list implementation is often called singly-linked list (or in functional languages cons-list).

The functional definition cuts straight to the structure of a list:

```
List := Empty | Cons T List
```

Of course, this does not really work in C or C++, so we need to cut the structure in two:

- The list is implemented as a chain of Node
- A List class hides this implementation detail

Here is some simple code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node(T t): element(t) {}

    T element;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
};

template <typename T>
class List {
    typedef Node<T> N;
public:
    List() {}

    bool empty() const { return head == nullptr; }

    T& front() { assert(!this->empty()); return head->elem; }
    T const& front() const { { assert(!this->empty()); return head->elem; }

    void pop() { assert(!this->empty()); swap(head, head->next); }

    void push(T t) {
        std::unique_ptr<N> n{ new Node {t} };

        n->next = std::move(head);

        head = std::move(n);
     }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<N> head;
};
```

As you can see, this list is just implemented as a stack, no iteration etc... Still, it's a good beginning :)

Comment: +1, but for a realistic cons-list, that would be `std::shared_ptr<>` rather than `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: why ? The truth is, I thought about it, but it's an error-prone representation for C++. Sharing mutable data makes things harder... and it introduces the risk of creating circles unexpectedly. Unique ownership is *much* easier not to mess up :)

Comment: Make the data immutable, as in a true cons-list, and it will make a lot more sense -- tailing a list and reusing it in other lists becomes essentially free. And if one is allowed to only prepend and not append, as in a true cons-list, then circular-referencing becomes impossible.

Answer (score 2):

As aix said, your best bet is to go with either...

- std::list, which is a doubly-linked list, which means it trades backward traversal speed for memory usage *or*
- the less widely implemented std::slist (called forward_list in C++11), which is singly-linked and can only be traversed in one way.

[Of course, cplusplus.com has reference information on both.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

As a part of the STL, both list implementations have been extensively tested, tuned and debugged. Both support the standard STL algorithms. There is almost no reason not to use them.

Comment: `slist` got a proper name in C++11: `std::forward_list`.